# indexing for faster search of lists in a file?

Tags: python

I have a file with around 100k lists and have a another file with again a list of around an average of 50.

I want to compare 2nd item of list in second file with the 2nd element of 1st file and repeat this for each of the 50 lists in 2nd file and get the result of all the matching element.

I have written the code for all this,but this is taking a lot of time as it need to check the whole the 100k list some 50 times. I want to improve the speed.

I cant not post my code as it is part of big code and will be difficult to infer anything from that.

Comment: Looks like `lakh` means 100,000, cfr http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh .

Comment: Ohh yes 1 lakh means 100,000 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can afford to read all the "lakh" (hundred thousands) lines from the first file in memory *once*:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('lakhlists.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        aslist = line.split()  # assuming whitespace separators
        d[aslist[1]].append(aslist)
```

you don't give us many crucial parameters but I'd bet this will fit in memory (for reasonable guesses at list lengths) on typical model platforms.  Assuming this part works, just looping over the other, small files, and indexing into `d` should be trivial in comparison;-)

If you care to express your specs, and the relevant numbers, more precisely (and ideally in English), maybe more specific help can be offered!

Comment: Ideally in English?? What language did you think his question was written in?

Comment: @John, "lakh" is not normally considered an English word (though I was able to look it up!-), so I was basically asking the OP to stick with "normal" English terminology (should he introduce more exotic terms in his prose, would-be responders might not be able to translate them into more normal English terms).